# xkb can't find rules in included path

Tags: qt, keyboard, vnc

I'm using Mac Screen Sharing app to connect to Ubuntu 14.04 vncserver a
The strage thing is that sometimes it doesn't find the rules right away when i launch the qt, and some other times the error message pops up later. I can't understand why this happens. The consequence is that i can't type anymore but only when the rule error message pops up.

```
xkbcommon: ERROR: Couldn't find file "rules/0" in include paths
xkbcommon: ERROR: 1 include paths searched:
xkbcommon: ERROR:       /usr/share/X11/xkb
xkbcommon: ERROR: 1 include paths could not be added:
xkbcommon: ERROR:       /home/angel/.xkb
xkbcommon: ERROR: Couldn't look up rules '0', model 'pc105', layout 'us', variant '(null)', options '^^'
Qt: Failed to compile a keymap
Qt: Failed to create xkb state
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
^[[C
angel@localhost:~$ /home/angel/Masternodes/BUCKS/MN3/GorillaBand3.sh
QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize XRandr
Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

#Here it worked for 5 minutes an then

xkbcommon: ERROR: Couldn't find file "rules/9^C" in include paths
xkbcommon: ERROR: 1 include paths searched:
xkbcommon: ERROR:       /usr/share/X11/xkb
xkbcommon: ERROR: 1 include paths could not be added:
xkbcommon: ERROR:       /home/angel/.xkb
xkbcommon: ERROR: Couldn't look up rules '9^C', model '^C', layout 'us', variant '(null)', options ''
```

I've tried using setxkbmap but when i do it returns:

```
XKB extension not present on :1.0
```

I've looked everywhere but i can't find a working solution.